# How to get Laravel handle Customer Subscription Deleted event handled properly.?

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController as CashierController;

class WebhookController extends CashierController
{
    /**
     * Handle invoice payment succeeded.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted(array $payload)
    {
        echo "hello";exit;
        // Handle The Event
    }
}
```

// Route - also skipped verify csrf

```
Route::post('stripe/webhook', '\Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController@handleWebhook');
```

Test webhook is triggered successfully, but response says empty.[image: laravel-cash]

Comment: Looking like the webhook is calling `handleWebhook` not `handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted`?

Comment: Looks like `WebhookController::missingMethod()` is returned which returns an empty response per default. This seems to happen if the [related method to the payload type](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/9.0/src/Http/Controllers/WebhookController.php#L34) couldn't be found.

Comment: @levi What is your suggestion here?

Comment: @Dan Any article on handling this case?

Comment: If `missingMethod()` is called, something went wrong. I suggest you debugging the request and the methods in question and finding out why exactly the `handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted()` method isn't called.

Comment: On handleWebhook() , there was this condition on top, commenting these lines passed the execution through -         if (! $this->isInTestingEnvironment() && ! $this->eventExistsOnStripe($payload['id'])) {
            return;
        }

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/7.0/src/Http/Controllers/WebhookController.php